# php post variable to next page as per condition check

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying post method to send var checking some condition

If user logged in then show button and on click post data to `ind.php`
if not logged in show label
code :

```
<?php
session_start();
$appId      = 'fgf';
$appSecret  = ''; // Facebook App Secret
$return_url = 'amazonaws.com/'; //path to script folder
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<title>ThenWat</title>
<script>
 function showUser(form, e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.returnValue=false;
        var sent = form.elements['sent'].value;
    alert(sent);
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open(form.method, form.action, true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
        xmlhttp.send(sent);
    }
</script>
 </head>
<body style="height: 560px">
    <?php
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
?>
     <form action="ind.php" method="POST" onsubmit="showUser(this, event)">
        <pre>
             <label>Enter the sentence: <input type="text" name="sent"></label><br/>
        </pre>
                <input type="submit" class="submit" name="insert" value="submit"/>
    </form>
<?php
}
?>
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
?>
 <label>not logged in </label>
<?php
}
?>
<div id="txtHint"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

ind.php

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$s=$_POST['sent'];
echo $s;

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Always says not logged in, and if I remove conditions data is not post on ind.php.
error: `Undefined index: sent in /opt/lampp/htdocs/a/FB/ec2/ind.php on line 5`

Comment: Ok, so what's the problem?

Comment: This would be so much easier / less typing in jQuery. Any reason to not use it?

Comment: what is your actual problem and what do you want?

Comment: @gibberish: jquery no issue. I have confused between ajax jquery. could not differentiate!

Comment: I needed more space to answer your above comment, so I posted a new "answer" -- it's not really an answer, just a reply to your comment, but hopefully more clear this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of clarity and simplicity, this solution uses jQuery.  I did ask above if jQuery is acceptable and did not receive an answer, so *if not desired please comment (rather than downvote) and I will remove the answer.*

Note that I assigned an ID attribute to your form, to more easily select it in the DOM. Without assigning an ID to the form, you can still select it, thus:

```
$('form').submit({});
```

however, that would be confusing if you ever had more than one form on the page. *Always best to use IDs with your elements so you can specify exactly the element you wish to select.*

Also, removed the `onSubmit()` from the form tag, and placed it with the rest of the javascript code, thus:

`$('#myForm').submit(function(e) {`

---

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
                    var sent = $('[name==sent]').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "ind.php",
                        data: "sent=" + sent
                    })
                    .done(function(recd) {
                        $('#txtHint').html(recd);
                    });
                    e.preventDefault();
                }); //END form submit

            }); //END document.ready
        </script>
    </head>

    <body style="height: 560px">
    <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    ?>
         <form id="myForm" action="ind.php" method="POST">
            Enter the sentence: <input type="text" name="sent"><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    <?php
        }
        if (!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    ?>
            <p>Not logged in </p>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
        <div id="txtHint"> </div>

</body>

</html>
```

---

Finally, your `ind.php` file only needs to have this:

```
<?php
    $s = $_POST['sent'];
    echo 'PHP side received: ' . $s;
```

Comment: thanks, but why it redirect to `ind.php` rather showing result in sample page `txtHint`?

Comment: When a form is submitted, it automatically redirects to the page specified in the `action="ind.php"` attribute. That is how forms work. To stop that default behavior, use `e.preventDefault()` -- that will stop the form from redirecting the page.

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` *will* stop a form from redirecting the page. If it does not, then either (1) the code does not get that far (is there other form submission code -- perhaps inline? -- that executes before the jQuery?), or (2) the `e.preventDefault()` has a syntax error somewhere -- have you used `function(e)` when defining the function? That `(e)` and the `e.` are matched pairs. [See this article](http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/) for more interesting info.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in your comment:

As you already know, javascript is a client-side programming language.

jQuery is a much simpler, more concise and consistent (and automatically cross-browser compatible) form of javascript. jQuery is a *library* that runs on top of javascript -- you type jQuery code, and it is converted into javascript at run time.

AJAX can be written in either javascript or jQuery -- but requires LOTS MORE code to do it in javascript. AJAX is just a procedure (not a language!) for exchanging data with a server without refreshing the page.

FORMS are a method of sending data from the browser page (client side) to the server, so that the server can process it. When a form submits, it *always* refreshes/redirects the page. It is possible for a form to submit *to the same page* by using `action=""` in the form tag (that is, not specifying a different page in the action attribute). However, this also will refresh the page. The only way to exchange data with the server but *not* refresh the page, is to use AJAX.

If you use AJAX and then you want to redirect the page somewhere else, you can use the javascript command:

```
window.location.href = "http://anotherpage.php";
```

The great advantage is to using AJAX with window.location.href is the flexibility it gives you. For example, you can:

- verify the user-supplied data first (returning control to user if any errors)
- send it to the server where it can be silently added into the database, then
- a further MySQL query can be run, based on the user's submitted data, and
- new HTML code can be sent back to the browser (arriving in the `success:` or `done` function)
- display a message to the user with information from the 2nd MySQL query, then
- redirect user to another page when you are ready

As you can see, AJAX gives much more control to the programmer.

Comment: very nice explaination. I tried to implement as per your answer in my original code. But with no luck, I will be grateful if you can dig http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029278/sending-json-string-to-next-page-using-jquery-ajax

Comment: Infact this is what I want to implement that you have bulleted!

Comment: If you want to test the code in quetion I redirected, I can share app ID. please let me know

Comment: I wish I could help more, but I don't have enough time. However, I can see why your questions are not being answered -- too open-ended. In other words, you are basically asking readers to make the script work for you. Instead, identify the exact spot where code is not doing what you want. This involves putting lots of tests at different spots in the code. When you find a break, design a NEW APP -- a very simple example app that only does that one thing. Then post that as a question for SO. We would love to help, but we must take only small bites -- not the entire meal.

Comment: Since you are getting data from another domain, you might be encountering problems with cross-domain requests. I don't know very much about that area, but you can look up JSONP and cross-domain requests. Design simple tests and get them to work first. Don't make the mistake of trying to solve all the problems at the same time: fix one capability at a time.

Comment: For right now, you should probably choose a correct answer to close the question, because this will show other responders that you can be trusted to give "accepts" (which is what we all work for...) Then, design some simple tests and make sure you can get the simple examples working before creating the entire project. When you have a problem with a simple app, it is much easier to get help on SO.